# cannot remove ?/cat= with 301 redirect in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Somehow I have this url being requested: example.com/wordpress/?cat=7

I have tried everything I could find and nothing works. I have a ton of redirects and using a plugin ruins them all so putting them one at a time into a plugin is not an answer.

I tried all of these too:

```
    redirect 301 /wordpress/?cat=7 sitename
    redirect 301 /wordpress sitename
    redirect 301 /wordpress/ 'sillything won't let me fill this in'
    redirect 301 /?cat=7  sitename
    RewriteRule ^/wordpress.*$ sitename? [R=301]
    RedirectMatch ^/wordpress.*$ sitename? [R=301]
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/wordpress.*$ sitename [QSD]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sitename\.com$
    RewriteRule ^wordpress\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/sitename\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I get "example.com/?cat=7"...no matter what I try.

I've tried redirectmatch, rewrite rules listed here...nothing removes the /?cat=7...so google shows a 404 and I cannot fix it.

I even tried a global redirect for all 404's and it failed also.
I checked all the offered examples but I must be missing something as none of them work.

HELP!

Thanks.

Comment: I can see a infinite LOOP in your rule after `RewriteEngine On` you're trying to redirect sitename.com and www.sitename.com to sitename.com and where the one without www is the same in the condition and in the redirect, are you sure the sitename is the same? Please do edit your question to fix that or we won't be able to properly help you. Also are all the Redirects above `RewriteEngine On` what you have tried?

Comment: Also `Redirect` directive doesn't work with QUERY STRING, use `mod_rewrite` rules only.

Comment: I did not write the loop thing...just mentioning it did not work, maybe for the reasons you say. And yes, I showed all of the examples because others elsewhere keep getting those and I wanted it known I'd tried all of them. Anyway, the question is still the same if anyone can help "How do I get http://www.sitename.com/wordpress/?cat=7 to redirect to http://www.sitename.com/ thanks!

Comment: Sorry, got cut off...I did not write the loop thing...just mentioning it did not work, maybe for the reasons you say. And yes, I showed all of the examples because others elsewhere keep getting those and I wanted it known I'd tried all of them. Also, the rules in the redirects at the top above were complete with the full url...it removes them here I guess, so it just gets 'sitename'...or I don't know how to do it right to show up here. Anyway, the question is still the same if anyone can help "How do I get http://www.sitename.com/wordpress/?cat=7 to redirect to http://www.sitename.com/ thanks!